# How do I manage optional whitespace in ANTLR?

Tags: java, whitespace, antlr

I am trying to parse a data file in ANTLR - it has optional whitespace exemplified by

```
 3 6
  97   12
 15 18
```

The following shows where the line starts and ends are. There is a newline at the end and there are no tabs.

```
^ 3 6$
^  97   12$
^ 15 18$
^
```

My grammar is:

```
lines   :   line+;
line    :   ws1 {System.out.println("WSOPT :"+$ws1.text+":");} 
                num1 {System.out.println("NUM1 "+$num1.text);} 
                ws2 {System.out.println("WS :"+$ws2.text+":");}
                num2 {System.out.println("NUM2 "+$num2.text);} 
                NEWLINE
    ;
num1    :    INT    ;
num2    :    INT    ;
ws1 :   WSOPT;
ws2 :   WS;

INT     : '0'..'9'+;
NEWLINE :    '\r'? '\n';
//WS    :   (' '|'\t' )+ ;
WS  :   (' ')+ ;
WSOPT   :   (' ')* ;
```

which gives

```
line 1:0 mismatched input ' ' expecting WSOPT
WSOPT :null:
NUM1 3
WS : :
NUM2 6
line 2:0 mismatched input '   ' expecting WSOPT
WSOPT :null:
NUM1 97
WS :   :
NUM2 12
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

(i.e. the leading WS has not been recognised and the last line has been missed).

I would like to parse lines which start without whitespace, such as:

```
^12    34$
^ 23 97$
```

but I then get errors such as:

```
line 1:0 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input ' '
```

I'd appreciate general explanations of parsing WS in ANTLR.

**EDIT** @jitter has a useful answer - `{ignore=WS}` does not appear in the "Definitive ANTLR reference" book that I am working from so it is clearly a tricky area.

**HELP still needed**
I have modified this to:

```
lines   :   line line line;
line
options { ignore=WS; }
        :
                ws1  {System.out.println("WSOPT :"+$ws1.text+":");} 
                num1 {System.out.println("NUM1 "+$num1.text);} 
                ws2  {System.out.println("WS :"+$ws2.text+":");}
                num2 {System.out.println("NUM2 "+$num2.text);} 
                NEWLINE
    ;
```

but get the error:

```
illegal option ignore
```

**EDIT** apparently this has been removed from V3:
http://www.antlr.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2007-February/019423.html

Comment: +1, I had the same problem and ended up using a major hack of the lemon parser. Following this with interest.

Comment: @tinkertim Thanks - it's always nice to know the question is not a complete dummy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get this working using lexer constructs such as:

```
WS  :   (' ')+ {skip();};

WSOPT   :       (' ')* {skip();};
```

but not in the NEWLINE. Then in the parser constructs such as:

```
num1 num2 NEWLINE;
```

The key was to strip all WS in the lexer except the NEWLINE.

Answer (score 10):

```
WS : (' ' | '\t')+
     {$channel = HIDDEN;}
   ;
```

Comment: Antlr4 version: WS : (' ' | '\t')+ -> channel(HIDDEN);

Answer (score 3):

Check [Lexical Analysis with ANTLR](http://www.antlr2.org/doc/lexer.html) and then search the part which starts with this heading

**Ignoring whitespace in the lexer**

You need to use the `{ ignore=WS; }` rule

Comment: Thanks - I will try this and report back. FWIW there are cases where the exact formatting also matters so I hope I can switch.

Comment: **EDIT** It appears this is not available in V3