# How can I get vim find to ignore whitespace?

Tags: vim

I have XML entries that span two or more lines sometimes, and so I can look for something like this:

```
something on one line
```

But if I try the vim command `/something on one line` and the line is like this:

```
something on one 
line
```

then it doesn't find it, because the second text block is actually seen as

```
something on one^J           line
```

Which might have something to do with the fact that I'm using a DOS formatted file.

How can I get vim search to ignore whitespace and newlines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In vim search, `_s` means a new line, a space or a tab. So you can try something such as:

```
/something on one\_s*line
```

to match the example string you used as example.

Comment: Better use `\_s\+` or it'll also match `oneline`.

Comment: But what if I don't know where in the string the whitespace is going to occur?

Comment: Good point @Jono: the answer was crafted on the original question, then anyone who needs this feature can change the command as required. If you don't know where the whitespace occurs, simply substitute every space in the query string: `/something\_s*on\_s*one\_s*line`

Comment: @IngoKarkat, I can't make `\_s\+` match against `oneline` (vim 7.4), `\_s*` instead works.. am I missing something?

Comment: That's the purpose of `\+`: match at least one. You usually want _any_ kind of space in between.

Comment: Adding to what @Jonathan asked: In those cases when we don't know where the whitespace is going to be, is there a way we can ignore all whitespaces everywhere? Like we do in Antlr (Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654186/how-do-i-manage-optional-whitespace-in-antlr)

Answer (score 3):

Replacing the  spaces with `\_s\+` manually is cumbersome. The [Search for visually selected text](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_for_visually_selected_text) topic on the Vim Tips Wiki has a mapping that does this for you for the current visual selection. You can use it like the built-in `*` mapping, to search (ignoring spaces) for the current selection. Very handy!

Answer (score 1):

While I like the existing answers, I was looking for a way to do the substitution of spaces to `\_s*` "automagically" for every search that I type.

Luckily, such a solution is possible, as explained in this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/ailgyc/any_way_to_change_spaces_to_any_whitespace_s_when/) post. I ended up using the following command:

```
cnoremap <expr><space> '/?' =~ getcmdtype() ? '\_s*' : ' '
```

This makes it so that whenever you type a space in a search command (either `/` or `?`), all spaces that you type are automatically replaced by `\_s*`.

In fact, I only wanted this behavior for LaTeX files, so I added the following to my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType tex cnoremap <expr><space> '/?' =~ getcmdtype() ? '\_s*' : ' '
```